# Error Logging in Nginx+Gunicorn+Supervisor+Django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

The I am logging all the caught errors in the django app in the django logger. Where do the errors that do not get caught go? It should go to supervisor log file, in my opinion. But that is empty.

Comment: They would be in supervisor if you log all uncached logs to console. Could you post your logging config?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to nginx [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html), add line to your configuration file.

```
access_log  /path/to/your/logs/nginx_access.log;
error_log  /path/to/your/logs/nginx_error.log info;
```

To log with supervisor, you can add lines to your configuration file like this

```
[program:program]
command=/virtualenv/python /path/to/django/source/manage.py run_gunicorn --log-file /path/to/your/logs/gunicorn.log
stdout_logfile=/path/to/your/logs/supervisor.log
```

As you see, gunicorn log is specified in parameter `log-file`

Finally in django settings you can do the logging according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/)